# Spring Boot MVC - How to generate etag value of an entity programatically?

Tags: spring-boot, etag

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.18 with ReactJs and I am trying to conditionally update an entity using an eTag.

I have added the following config and Spring Boot is generating the etags in the response headers.

```
@Bean
public Filter shallowEtagHeaderFilter() {
    return new ShallowEtagHeaderFilter();
}
```

Now I want to check in my controller method if the etags match before updating the entity. My controller method is as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(method = POST, value = "/assignments/{id}/edit")
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<?> editStaffAssignment(@RequestBody Resource<AssignmentDTO> dtoResource,
                                      @PathVariable Long id,
                                      PersistentEntityResourceAssembler resourceAssembler, Pageable pageable) {

    Assignment assignment = assignHandler.updateAssignment(dtoResource.getContent(), id);

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resourceAssembler.toResource(assignment), HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

I have included the etag header in the Axios request from the reactjs client and I can extract it in the controller method but how do I generate the current etag value on the server side programatically?

Answer (score 2):

The `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` calculates the ETag value based on the serialized response body, so it's not easily possible to calculate it upfront (i.e. before the response body is actually sent).

If I understand you correctly you want to employ an optimistic locking mechanism. If that's the case I'd suggest to drop the `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` and instead calculate the ETag manually in the first place, like this:

```
String etag = calculateETag(); // TODO
return ResponseEntity.ok()
      .eTag(etag)
      .body(resourceAssembler.toResource(assignment));
```

If using JPA you could re-use the `@Version` field as an ETag value here.